# Windows phone redirect to app store to update app

Tags: c#, cordova, windows-phone

Really simple question, but I was not able to find answers relating to this.

I have a Phonegap application which is updated regularly and they must update the app before logging into the app. Currently I prompt the user with a upgrade button.

My question is how do I redirect them from my app. to the Windows store pointing to my app to let me them update and once that is done reopen my app?

I found out the routines to call to achieve this, this redirects them to  the app store but I am not sure if the app store is the same as update page or that app. how do I send them directly to update the app.

*Note: I am unable to test this yet, since my app has not be approved yet to be published on the app but, but I  would like to know the answer so once it is approved the changes will work. Thanks

call upon `MarketplaceDetailTask` class from `using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks`;

```
MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
marketplaceDetailTask.ContentIdentifier = "{your unique app guid goes here}";
marketplaceDetailTask.ContentType = MarketplaceContentType.Applications;
marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
```

Comment: Updating every time a user opens the app sounds like a pain to me.  What are you updating so frequently?

Comment: its not ever time , usually once a month. its a business App. that requires an update before enabling users to log in

Comment: Is it an update to the way the application works, or to some data that the application uses?

Comment: it can be both, data and functionality

Comment: For data updates you're probably better off using a web service that the app can check for data updates at start-up.

Comment: I already have a web service that checks that, I just want to redirect the app to the update page, when my web service returns that there is an update. Is there a way to redirect them to Update page on windows phone?

Comment: I'm not sure about the direct answer to your question, but my point is that for data updates you shouldn't need the redirect to the store.  Just download the new data from the web service and store it with a timestamp or version number on the device.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need to check user installed version and version in the Store - if user is running lower version you can use your above code to redirect to Store app page for triggering update. If user and store has same version, you can load the app.

In order to do latest version checks, you might need to have the latest version number somewhere in the net - have checked it in the app.

you can use below code to do version checks:
http://bjorn.kuiper.nu/2011/10/01/wp7-notify-user-of-new-application-version/